# Can I iterate different images in a Word doc with an openTBS template using PHP?

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have a MS Word document with a block of 3 cells and another 3 cells down below. Inside each cell there is a different thing: in three cells there are text, which work just fine, and inside the other three there are images.

I have six different blocks that I load into this document, one for each cell.

The problem I am having is that I cannot find anywhere how to iterate through a block when it's an image - the text cells are working just fine but I don't know which tag should I try to add at the image.

This is one of the text cells:

```
[col1.signatura;block=tbs:row+tbs:row]
```

And the image alt:

```
[bar2.code;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside;default=current]
```

I tried using:

```
[bar2.code;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside;default=current;block=tbs:row+tbs:row]
```

but it didn't work as expected and it created a blank document.

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: It's difficult for me to  figure out how are arranged the tables row and cells of your template. Can you give a draft or a real template ?